# Troubles with PHP session and Objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, session, nsurlconnection

I have two methods of two different classes.

Class 'A' has the login function which uses NSURLConnection I perform a login. Class 'B' has a whole different function that, once logged-in, retrieves some data with another nSURLConnection call.

Function 'B' can be done only if I'm already logged in, and that's the problem. Once I first login, it says I'm succesfully logged in, but when I call the other method, I'm being rejected because it says I'm not logged in.

So I thought was a session problem, I searched a lot and found this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    NSArray *allCookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[urlResponse allHeaderFields] forURL:[response URL]];

    if ([allCookies count]) {
        [connection cancel];

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:allCookies forURL:[response URL] mainDocumentURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"fatto cookie! %@", allCookies);
    }
}
```

That I call in class 'A' so that it "theoretically" saves my session globally, but it doesn't.

Can anybody help me with that? What am I missing?

Thanks.